# Print to an open excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file stored in a network drive, the file will stay open by a single user. Is there a way to be able to print records to this file while is open? 
When I run the code below, it opens the file in read only. I only want to write.

```
    Dim con as object
    Set con =CreateObject("ADODB. Connection")
    con.ConnectionString=constr
    On error resume next
    con.Open
    Dim cmd as object
    Set cmd =CresteObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection =con
    cmd.CommandText =SQL 'INSERT'
    cmd.Execute
    con.Close
```

Comment: If the file is already open (unless in read-only mode) you can't write to it.  What's the actual use case though?

Comment: There is a way, but it is *very* far-fetched. If you make the owning process listening to messages and act on them, you have created a database server. The better way is to use a real database server.